# Can no longer simply edit comments in excel 10

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

excel 10.  I have 100's of comments in many cells on a very large workbook. I am often sorting over 3000 lines of data as well as adding and subtracting lines. I have had to relocate where the comments appear on my workbook by using paste special > comments, many times.  Now I cannot edit comments without going to review show all comments and then click on the cell that I have added a comment into.  How do I get my program back to being able to hover over a comment and then edit without these extra steps?   thanks for your help

Comment: If the posted answer(s) don't do what you want, please describe in more detail  (1) What you did before, that worked (and what version of Excel it was),  (2) What you want to do (in case that's different from (1) ),  (3) What happens when you try (2) in Excel 2010, and  (4) What you are doing (in Excel 2010) that works.   If I'm misunderstanding the big picture, please correct me.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

Check under `File/Options/Advanced/Display`, there is a block with '`For comments, show`'.

There you can chose '`indicators only, and comments on hover`'.

Comment: I went through the steps that you suggested, but it still did not work.  Something must happen to the comments when I adjust their location by using COPY, PASTE SPECIAL, COMMENTS. Those comments are the ones that I cannot edit easily.  New comments that I add to the workbook still function normally.

Comment: Do you use line hiding/filtering? Excel behaves strange when a comment is adjusted while lines are hidden or views are fixed. If so, try to open all filters (row numbers on the left will turn black instead of blue), and adjust one comment now., and see if it goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  And it is very simple.  All I had to do was widen the cells that held the comments.  I was immediately able to edit the comments.  Who would of thought of that....

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over the cell with the new style comment, the comment box will pop up... now hover over the comment box to see the "Edit" link in the lower right portion of the box.  I'm not sure why there are options to "Reply" and "Delete" from the context menu (right-click on cell) while "Edit" is done through a totally different mechanism.